# Making Objective-C code asyncronous without changing control flow

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous

We currently have a method like the following:

```
-(void)DoTask{
   //METHOD 1

   //METHOD 2

   //METHOD 3

  //METHOD 4

}
```

We've found a bug and the fix requires us to make sure Method 3 is executed async. It happens throughout the entire system so we're hoping for a simple fix. Is there a way of just putting some type of wrapper method around the code that we need to run Async so the code flow doesn't need to change for the main method? So pretty much like:

```
-(void)DoTask{
   //METHOD 1

   //METHOD 2

   //WRAPPER START AROUND METHOD 3 TO MAKE IT ASYNC
   //METHOD 3
   //WRAPPER END AROUND METHOD 3 AFTER ASYNC HAS FINISHED FOR CODE TO GO ONTO METHOD 4

  //METHOD 4

}
```

Comment: Do you mean method 4 need to be executed on the main thread and method 3 should be executed on the other thread ?

Comment: If you run method 3 async then you have no assurance that it will complete prior to method 4.  (And, no, in your main thread you may not insert a "wait" for method 3 to complete.)  Otherwise it's a relatively simple task to split a body of code off as a separate task, so long as you manage the variable sharing carefully.

Comment: And, you know, taking a large method and splitting it up shouldn't be that burdensome of a task if the code is halfway decently structured to begin with.  Sometimes you just need to bite the bullet.

Comment: Incidentally, it's total nonsense to say "Making Objective-C code asyncronous without changing control flow".  Asynchronous code, by definition, is not subject to the constraints of normal "control flow".

Comment: If you're waiting for a task to complete before proceeding, that task is, by definition, not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't* do that (what you're describing would be **synchronous**, not **asyncronous**).

You have a few options. You can call method 4 after method 3's asynchronous operation is complete:

```
-(void) doTask{
    //METHOD 1

    //METHOD 2

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //METHOD 3

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //METHOD 4
        });
    });
}
```

You could also call method 4 first.

You could also use `NSOperationQueue` to chain your operations and set which operations require others to be complete. This allows you to run multiple operations concurrently.

---

* - Technically, you *can* do that, by blocking one thread until another completes, but you almost certainly *shouldn't* do that.